# hosting website own server while uploading file how to chose my computer directory?

Tags: file, file-upload, hosting, web-hosting

I'm hosting my website on server and when i'm going to choose file uption it give me error.the file choosen is working perfectly in local server but problem on hosting server the error message screen short is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1YC5.png)

Comment: Upload in MVC 5 doesn't work with server but work locally in vs

Answer (score 0):

I have got salution own my strugle.The answer is

im hosting my website on plesk server and when i upload file it don't give me permission for write on folder .folder may make changes on my plesk web host server inside my project i have made changes and give aceess to write.